# (PHP) Why is this the output of the following echo?

Tags: php, function, class

I'm going through some PHP question for my exam, and in the question below, apparently (B) is the answer.

> What is the output of the following code?
>
> ```
> class Magic {
>   public $a = 'A';
>   protected $b = array('a' => 'A', 'b' => 'B', 'c' => 'C');
>   protected $c = array(1, 2, 3);
>
>   public function __get($v) {
>     echo "$v,";
>     return $this->b[$v];
>   }
>
>   public function __set($var, $val) {
>     echo "$var: $val,";
>     $this->$var = $val;
>   }
> }
>
> $m = new Magic;
> echo $m->a.','.$m->b.','.$m->c.',';
> $m->c = 'CC';
> echo $m->a.','.$m->b.','.$m->c;
> ```
>
> - A: A,Array,Array,A,Array,Array,CC
> - B: b,c,A,B,C,c: CC,b,c,A,B,C
> - C: a,b,c,A,B,C,c: CC,a,b,c,A,B,C
> - D: b,c,A,B,C,c: CC,b,c,A,B,CC

Sorry for the noob question, but coming from Java, I can't for the life of me understand why this is the correct answer.

Comment: If you code it and test it, you will be able to answer your own question

Comment: @RiggsFolly - I have haha, I even played about with it. I see what's going on, but I'm just trying to understand why it does what it does.

Comment: @RiggsFolly - Literally the only thing that made clear concrete sense to me was the result of `$m->c = "CC";`

Comment: Code posted on this website should be typed, not part of an image.

Comment: Please post the actual text code then, if you tested it. And then try to be specific about your question. Explaining why *everything* is happening the way it is would take a lot of time. What part do you need help with?

Comment: @LuminousNutria - Sorry about that, had no idea.

Comment: It's okay, the rules can be complex.

Comment: @Jeto - I apologise for not being clear, I just wasn't clear myself as to what was actually going on. I'll just try figure it out myself and take the question  down.

Comment: Don't delete your question! That's a big no-no here. You can get banned from asking any more by doing that.

Comment: @LuminousNutria - Sorry, again. Was just telling myself to stop being lazy and work harder to figure out what's going on haha

Comment: That's alright. My suggestion, if you have the time, is to edit your question to show how you've tried to figure it out yourself. If you figure it out, you can post your own answer here.

Comment: @LuminousNutria you have to do a lot of self-deleting to get yourself banned.

Comment: @miken32 I'm not sure if there are clear guidelines on it.  I didn't mean to imply you could get banned by doing it once.  I got question-banned over three deleted questions. There may be other factors too. I don't think self-deletion of answers and comments is treated as harshly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$b` and `$c` are a protected properties so they cannot be set from outside the class scope. `$a` is public so it can be set/accessed directly.

For accessing `$b` and `$c`, it will fallback to the magic getter which retrieves the values from the `$b` array.

The logic follows:

```
b, <- getter echo (executed by $m->b)
c, <- getter echo (executed by $m->c)
A, <- public property value (this is the start of the first global echo expression)
B, <- getter return b[b]
C, <- getter return b[c]
c: CC, <- setter echo, sets c = CC, but c is never accessed
b, <- getter echo (executed by $m->b)
c, <- getter echo (executed by $m->c)
A, <- public property value (this is the start of the second global echo expression)
B, <- getter return b[b]
C <- getter return b[c]
```

The getter echoes are processed first because their echo statements are reached before the echoed expression (with concatenation) has finished evaluating.

Since `$a` is public, no magic setters or getters are used.

Comment: For what it's worth, B _is_ actually the right answer

Comment: b is the correct answer. Anything that is echoed within `__get` will be displayed before the whole string has been concatenated/computed, and only then the values *returned* by property access or `__get` (aka, the result of the concatenation) will be displayed.

Comment: Yeah, now that he added the code, I see and tested that.  I'll remove this.

Comment: I'd suggest removing to edit it and reposting it; there's still a lot of good information in this answer, especially regarding the protected properties

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, makes sense :)

Answer (score 3):

Does this cut down version make it any clearer?

```
class Magic
{
    public $a = "A";
    protected $b = ['a' => 'A', 'b' => 'B', 'c' => 'C'];

    public function __get($v)
    {
        echo "A MAGIC METHOD IS BEING CALLED TO GET THE PROPERTY $v", PHP_EOL;
        return $this->b[$v];
    }
}

$m = new Magic;
echo ($m->a . ',' . $m->b . ',' . $m->c);
```

> A MAGIC METHOD IS BEING CALLED TO GET THE PROPERTY b
>   A MAGIC METHOD IS BEING CALLED TO GET THE PROPERTY c
>   A,B,C

I suppose the point is to demonstrate two things:

1. That PHP's [magic](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) `__get` method is only called for properties that are not directly accessible (i.e. not public). The implementation of the method can then return any string at all - in this case the property name is used to look up an element of a different array.
2. That variables concatenated into a string are resolved before the string is used. So the `__get` method is called twice (for the inaccessible properties `b` and `c`), and the echo statement *inside* that method is called before the string itself is concatenated and displayed.

The call to set the property `c` between the two "echo" lines is similarly resolved using the `__set` method, although it doesn't haven't any impact on the rest of the code.

Demo: https://3v4l.org/4Bitg

Comment: Even I overlooked point 2 before I was able to test the real code.

Comment: @Devon Yep, same here. I generally use commas instead of concatenation to output several things at once, so I'm used to the them being resolved and displayed in order.

Comment: @Devon To be fair that's really awkward and should almost never happen in a real situation. Echoing stuff and generally having side effects within `__get` is super ugly :)

Comment: @iainn Which is a great habit to have and something like 5% of PHP developers seem to do, unfortunately. Quite a bit more efficient too (no concatenation, no need to buffer the whole string).

Comment: Thank you so much, been stuck on this for 3 days straight. Makes sense, had a feeling it had something to do with the fact that b and c are protected. Just didn't know what it was, thanks again :)

Answer (score -1):

The apparent answer is wrong (Or you had a typo while writing it down):

```
B: b,c,A,B,C,c: CC,b,c,A,B,C
```

The sequence `C,c` is not possible, it has to be `c,C`, when accessing `$m->c`.

Comment: I ran it and it gave me `C,c`

Comment: Don't forget about the `"$var: $val,"` bit in the setter! :)

Comment: @UndercoverCoder You're right, executes like that... Well, should go back to school it seems :P (At least I was right with regards to `$m->c` - if it was standalone it would produce `c,C` :http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9257dbc028bad74360bb3a5bf4bbf05aaec19f55

Comment: Ah, haha, now i See :-) method calls are chained by `.`, so THAT part is echoed after the echos inside the methods. @UndercoverCoder be aware that nobody does this messy stuff in the real world :P

Comment: @dagnose - Haha I'm glad this is not common practice. Would flip my keyboard multiple times.